# How to pull data from an encrypted website

Tags: database, excel

I have a site online and I want to make a database from the site. It is in certain format but I want to take the data from the site and import it into excel or access. Which is the best way to do this considering the data is encrypted so I cannot log in on the webbrowser in excel.

Comment: Your question is not making sense. You have a database? or you have a site?

Comment: Sorry I have a site online and I want to make a database from the site